# How to set type of NewItem that will be inserted in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have bound DataGrid's ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, now the problem is that `T` is an abstract class, and collection can only contain T derived types only.

I am watching InitializingNewItem event of DataGrid, but this only lets me set properties, Instead I would like to create an Item by myself and add it to the datagrid or set it as New Item place holder at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly if a default constructor doesnt exist in the `T` then its difficult to have a new row functionality enabled.

You will have to manage this on your own. Upon on demand `Add`, a new item of **derived type of T** can be added to the observable collection. Dont let any new `Add` to take place unless this element is properrly populated and committed.

Comment: For this user will have to click a button, but I want user to simply type values in the last new empty row, I want user to use inbuilt add new row functionality.

Comment: Isnt this possible if you handle `LostFocus` from `DataGridRow`, and check if the focus lost row corresponds to the empty item and thus commit \ validate and reject changes done to the row?

Comment: I don't know about these events and that is why I have asked this question. I get InitializingNewItem but AddNewItem method internally used by data grid is private. In the event I can only change properties but I can not Change or assign new item of my own. I know data grid used ListViewCollection and I can create my own ListViewCollection but even that does not have any properties or methods I can override.

Comment: I also facing the same problem, what we want is use datagrid's inbuilt new row functionality, I don't see what even I can use to set my own type and generate the new item type by my own...

Answer (score 1):

Its a hack, but sometimes using reflection is the simplest.

```
// hook on ItemsSource property change
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
    ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, 
    typeof(ItemsControl)).AddValueChanged(dataGrid, 
    delegate
        {
            if (null == dataGrid.ItemsSource)
                return;

            var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
            // and specify your type of constructor
            var constructorField = view.GetType().GetField("_itemConstructor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            constructorField.SetValue(view, typeof(MyItemType).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        });
```

Comment: Does not work for on abstract class. I have to give type in an event.